# When GCC does not provide __cpp_lib_uncaught_exceptions feature?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

Following piece of code does not work right on Alpine Linux:

```
#ifndef __cpp_lib_uncaught_exceptions
namespace std {
    int uncaught_exceptions() noexcept {
        return std::uncaught_exception();
    }
}
#endif
```

[Source](https://github.com/Beckhoff/ADS/blob/master/tools/fructose/test_root.h)

Error:

```
[ 89%] Linking CXX executable AdsLibTest.bin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/11.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/11.2.1/../../../../lib/libstdc++.a(eh_catch.o): in function `std::uncaught_exceptions()':
/home/buildozer/aports/main/gcc/src/gcc-11.2.1_git20220219/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_catch.cc:149: multiple definition of `std::uncaught_exceptions()'; CMakeFiles/AdsLibTest.bin.dir/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x8d0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [_deps/ads-build/AdsLibTest/CMakeFiles/AdsLibTest.bin.dir/build.make:98: _deps/ads-build/AdsLibTest/AdsLibTest.bin] Error 1
```

It looks like GCC does not provide `__cpp_lib_uncaught_exceptions` feature. Why this could happen?

Comment: Even if this compiles, this is a bad idea! The `bool` version of this function was removed from the standard for a reason: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception

Comment: ... and the relevant part of that page appears to link to [this](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm).  Written by Herb Sutter himself, the exception maestro.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I think this is "okay" if the goal is to make pre-C++17 compilation simulate the C++17 `std::uncaught_exceptions()` using what's available pre-C++17. That said, it assumes all the newest compilers always support that feature (I don't know if it's normally considered optional); seems like the safer test would be to only insert that fallback version when you know you're C++14 or earlier, and have some other, even more useless fallback for C++17 or later when the feature macro isn't defined.

Comment: I think this should be reported as bug. It clearly causes undefined behavior, but even if letting this slide as a hack it doesn't generally work. As mentioned by @ShadowRanger there is an `inline` missing and there is no protection against duplicate symbols from the standard library implementation if the language standard is set to pre-C++17, but C++17 still supported generally. Going by the commit, instead a new `inline` function (not inside `std`) should have been introduced which conditionally calls `std::uncaught_exceptions` or `std::uncaught_exception` based on the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding declarations to `namespace std` causes (with a few specific exceptions) undefined behavior. There is no reason that this should work, even if the compiler does correctly report that it doesn't provide `std::uncaught_exceptions`.

In particular, if the standard library implementation supported `std::uncaught_exceptions` and the file was compiled with language standard set to below C++17, then the feature test will claim that `std::uncaught_exceptions` is unsupported, but the standard library `.a`/`.so` may still provide the definition for it. This would cause a duplicate definition error.

As @ShadowRanger notes, there is also likely an `inline` missing on the function definition, because it may be included in multiple in multiple translation units.

Also, in order to use a feature test macro, it is necessary to include `<version>` (since C++20) or the header file corresponding to that features, e.g. in this case `<exception>`. Otherwise the macro is not defined and the feature check will always fail. It seems that the header is not including `<exception>`, but is including `<stdexcept>` though, which technically is not sufficient. However, practically, `<stdexcept>` is likely going to include `<exception>` and hence that would likely still work. For current libstdc++ this seems to be the case at least.

So, I would assume that your issue lies in the chosen compiler options, e.g. the language standard to compile for.

Comment: It has `#include <stdexcept>` and I guess `<exception>` is included too.

Comment: It also works with `#include <stdexcept>`. It fails only if I remove `include` at all.

Answer (score 2):

I see a few issues with your code:

1. `__cpp_lib_uncaught_exceptions` [is only documented to be defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/feature_test) (when applicable) if you've `#include`-ed `<version>` or `<exception>`; you've included neither. Add `#include <exceptions>` above that feature test somewhere, and it *should* work.
2. Your code as written will redefine `uncaught_exceptions()` in every compilation unit that includes it when the macro is not defined, because you made the definition in a header and did not make it `inline`, `static` or both, so *every* `.cpp` file including your header ends up getting its own exportable definition. Without the necessary headers included in your header, whether that feature test macro is defined will depend on whether each `.cpp` file includes `<exception>`/`<version>`, and whether it does so before or after including your header. If they aren't uniform, some files could get your header's definition, while others get the built-in definition.

Comment: Just a note. This is not my code but "FRUCTOSE C++ unit test library" by Andrew Peter Marlow. Am I right that including `stdexcept` does not guaranty including `exception`? This is a bit counterintuitive because types in that header extend `exception` class.

Comment: @JohnTracid: it's perfectly possible for both of those standard headers to include a third, implementation-specific, header where `class exception` is defined, but neither of the public headers includes the other public header.